# Understanding FacetGrid/Barplot Inconsistencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, facet-grid

I was doing some EDA, and I observed the following behavior with Seaborn.

**Seaborn version**: `0.12.2`

**Matplotlib version**: `3.7.1`

**Input data**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Class': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        'count': [509, 61, 18, 29, 8, 148, 54, 361, 46],
        'greek_char': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Beta'],
        'value': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

```py
fig = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="greek_char", hue="Class")

\_ = fig.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="value", y="count", dodge=True)
```

I obtained the following graph:

[image]

Here are some inconsistencies:

- Notice that Alpha doesn't have C in the dataset, but it appears in the graph.
- Alpha A has only Class 0, however, I see both classes in the graph.
- Class G and D are missing in the graph.

I would appreciate any help in determining whether this behavior is a bug, expected behavior, or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try running your code using `fig.map` instead of `fig.map_dataframe`, you'll get the warning, `UserWarning: Using the barplot function without specifying 'order' is likely to produce an incorrect plot.` Once I add the `order` argument, I get the correct plot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {"Class":[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        "count":[509, 61, 18, 29, 8, 148, 54, 361, 46],
        "greek_char":["Alpha"]*4 + ["Beta"]*5,
        "value":["A", "B", "D", "G", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="greek_char", hue="Class")
fig = fig.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, 
                        x="value", 
                        y="count", 
                        order=sorted(df["value"].unique()))
fig.add_legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- As per [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html):

  > Warning: In most cases, it will be better to use a figure-level function (e.g. [`relplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) or [`catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot)) than to use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) directly.

  - There is no reason to use `FacetGrid` in this case.
  - Correctly plotting with `catplot` resolves the issues of the data not being plotted in the correct `'value'`.
- Additionally, `'Beta'` → `'value': B & C` have overlapping `'Class'` data, which means the bars are layered, not stacked. Layering bars is a non-standard presentation of data, and is likely to be misinterpreted.

  - [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) does not do stacked bars.
- There are several options to plot the data correctly:

  1. The bars should be dodged. - This is the best option.
  2. [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with [`kind='hist'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) can stack bars.

     - This is a hacky way to use `histplot`, and may have unforeseen behaviors, such as including the extra x-axis position for `'Beta'`.
  3. The bars can be plotted with a unique value on the x-axis, and then relabeled with the correct `'value'`.

     - `df.reset_index(names=['x-axis'], inplace=True)` will produce a unique set of values to plot on the x-axis.
- Setting the order of the `'value'` on the x-axis can be done with:

  1. `df.sort_values(['greek_char', 'value'], inplace=True)`: [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
  2. Alternatively, [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) can be used, but this forces all `'value'` categories to be on both x-axes.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `pandas 2.0.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### 1. `dodge=True`

```py
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='value', y='count', hue='Class', col='greek_char', sharey=False)
```

[image]

### 2. `histplot`

```py
g = sns.displot(kind='hist', data=df, x='value', weights='count', hue='Class', col='greek_char', multiple='stack', shrink=0.9, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]

### 3. `dodge=False` with unique labels

```py
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='x-axis', y='count', hue='Class', col='greek_char', sharey=False, sharex=False, dodge=False)

# iterate through each facet (axes)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    # get the title to be used to select the correct data
    gc = ax.get_title().split(' = ')[1]
    # extract the values to be used for xticklabels
    xtick_labels = df.loc[df.greek_char.eq(gc), 'value'].tolist()
    # set the labels
    ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks(), xtick_labels)
```

[image]

---

- In general, `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with `kind='bar'`, and `stacked=True`, is the best option for plotting stacked bars, because the API is specifically designed to implement them.

```py
# create the figure and subplot axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 4), tight_layout=True)

# iterate through each axes, and the group / data of the groupby object
for ax, (g, data) in zip(axes, df.groupby('greek_char')):
    
    # pivot the data into a wide-form
    data = data.pivot(index='value', columns='Class', values='count')
    
    # plot the stacked bars
    data.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, ylabel='count', title=g, ax=ax)
    
    # cosmetic change
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
    
# adjust the legends so there is only one
axes[0].get_legend().remove()
axes[1].legend(title='Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

---

#### `df`

```py
df.sort_values(['greek_char', 'value'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(names=['x-axis'], inplace=True)

   x-axis  Class  count greek_char value
0       0      0    509      Alpha     A
1       1      1     61      Alpha     B
2       2      1     18      Alpha     D
3       3      1     29      Alpha     G
4       4      1      8       Beta     A
5       5      0    148       Beta     B
6       6      1     54       Beta     B
7       7      0    361       Beta     C
8       8      1     46       Beta     C
```